# How can I quick fire explosive gel on the ground?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I want to know how to quick fire explosive gel on the ground in Batman Arkham Origins.

How do I quick fire explosive gel on the ground?

Answer (score 3):

According to IGN's [Batman: Arkham Origins Tips, Tricks, and Tactics page](http://www.ign.com/wikis/batman-arkham-origins/Tips,_Tricks,_and_Tactics),

- **Xbox 360**: LT + X
- **PS3**: L2 + Square
- **Wii U**: LT + Y